# 'Can not read property then' error when using service

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a json in `controller` using `service` but I am receiving an error saying  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". I tried existing answers but couldn't get it to work.

Controller:

```
app.controller("myController",["$scope","MyService","$http", function($scope,MyService,$http){
$scope.hi = "hello";
MyService.getMyData().then(function(response){
console.log(response);
});
}]);
```

Service:

```
app.service("MyService", ["$http", function($http) {

  this.getMyData = function() {
    return
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'myList.json',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log(error);
      return response;
    });
  };
}]);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you had just `return`(on first line) thereafter on next line you returned `$http` promise. Basically you have `return` alone it returns nothing/undefined (this is how javascript works) & next statements are getting ignored from `this.getMyData` function.

You have to have `return` &  `$http({` promise to be together in one line, otherwise `return` will return empty statement.

```
this.getMyData = function() {
    //`return` & `$http` promise should be on same line, otherwise undefined would get return
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'myList.json',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log(error);
      return response;
    });
};
```

Comment: Here is a plunker with return on the same line (and I cleaned up the code a bit): https://plnkr.co/edit/KHQ8lj1rdkwyanRyiOt7?p=preview

Comment: downvoter may I know reason behind the downvote? would you mind to explain what wrong with answer?

Answer (score 1):

@pankajparker is absolutely correct.

Implemented a codepen for kicks and adjusted to use Angular 1.5's components.  Here's the link:
http://codepen.io/Lethargicgeek/pen/YWryoE

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("myApp", []);

  angular.module("myApp").component('myCmp', {
    controller: ctrlFn,
    templateUrl: "myCmp.tpl.html"
  });

  ctrlFn.$inject = ["myService"];

  function ctrlFn(myService) {
    var $ctrl = this;
    // BINDINGS 
    $ctrl.hi = "hello";
    $ctrl.getData = getData;
    $ctrl.data = null;

    $ctrl.myService = myService; // Binding so that we can easily see results
    // END BINDINGS

    // FUNCTION
    function getData() {
        var returnedPrms = myService.getMyData();
        returnedPrms.then(function(response) {
          $ctrl.data = response;
        });
      }
      // END FUNCTIONS 
  }

  angular.module("myApp").service("myService", svcFn);
  svcFn.$inject = ["$http"];

  function svcFn($http) {
    var svc = this;
    //BINDINGS
    svc.getMyData = getMyData;
    //END BINDINGS

    function getMyData() {

      var firstPrms = $http.get("http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVEwdw.js"); // Random bit of json pulled from internets
      var secondPrms = firstPrms.then(function success(response) {
        svc.successResp = response;
        return response;
      }, function error(response) {
        svc.errorResp = response;
        return response;
      });
      return secondPrms;
    }
  }
})(); // end iife
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myCmp.tpl.html">
    <div>
      <h1>{{$ctrl.hi}}</h1>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.getData()">
       Trigger $Http Call
      </a>

      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>$ctrl.data:</dt>
        <dd>{{$ctrl.data}}</dd>

        <dt>$ctrl.myService.successResp:</dt>
        <dd>{{$ctrl.myService.successResp}}</dd>

        <dt>ctrl.myService.errorResp:</dt>
        <dd>{{ctrl.myService.errorResp}}</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </script>

  <my-cmp></my-cmp>
</div>
```